# $KC$ property is hereditarily.

Tags: general-topology

A topological spece $X$ is KC if every compact subset is closed.

I know that the $KC$ property is hereditary for subspaces.

I would like to know if the following is true:

> **A toplogical space $X$ is KC iff every compact subset of $X$ is $KC$**

I mean, is it true that "if every compact subset of $X$ is $KC$, then $X$ is KC "?

Comment: if $X$ is $T_{2}$ (i.e. hausdorff spaces) then every compact subset is closed (in $X$).
Which topological spaces you is considered?

Comment: will $X$ be $KC$ space, if $K \subset X$ is compact and KC?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that every compact subset of $X$ is $KC$. If $X$ is not $KC$, then there is a compact $K\subseteq X$ that is not closed in $X$. Let $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_XK)\setminus K$, and let $K'=K\cup\{p\}$; $K'$ is a compact subset of $X$, so $K'$ is $KC$. But then $K$ is a compact subset of $K'$, so $K$ is closed in $K'$, $\{p\}$ is open in $K'$, and there is an open $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\cap K'=\{p\}$. Thus, $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$ in $X$ such that $U\cap K=\varnothing$, which contradicts the assumption that $p\in\operatorname{cl}_XK$, thereby showing that $K$ must be closed in $X$ and hence that $X$ is $KC$.

Comment: In KC Spaces," $X$ is a $KC$ space then for each $k‎\geq 2$, $X^k $ is $KC$ iff each compact subset of $X$ is Housdorff." Does  this theorem hold only for finite $k$?